# Non-emptiness of the relative interior in the infinite-dimensional case

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $E$ be a finite-dimensional space and let $C \subseteq E$ be a nonempty convex set. Then, the relative interior of $C$, which we denote by $\mbox{ri}(C)$, is nonempty.

If space $E$ is infinite-dimensional, does the result above still hold?

$$ ri(C)= \{x \in \operatorname{aff}(C): B[x,\epsilon] \cap \operatorname{aff}(C) \subseteq C \text{ for some } 
  \epsilon>0\}$$

Comment: What is the relative interior of $\{0\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @DavidKraemer, itself?

Comment: I don't think so. So the original statement does not hold even when $E = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @DavidKraemer But you should think so, since it is true. The affine hull of the origin is just the origin itself, since that is already an affine subspace. The relative interior of any affine subspace is of course the subspace itself, since "relative" here refers to "relative to the affine hull".

Comment: @Christoph, oh you're right. I'm just an idiot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your notation right then a subset $C=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} [-2^{-n};2^{-n}]$ of the space $\ell_2$ has empty relative interior, because $\operatorname{aff} C$ contains $x+e_n$ for each $x\in C$ and each $n$, where $e_n$ is the standard unit vector of $\ell_2$, but $x+2^{2-n} e_n\not\in C$.

Comment: This subset $C$ is even compact.