# Relative interior of convex set and its closure coincide in infinite dimensional spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

> Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, and $C\subset X$ a convex set. Is it always true $\text{ri}(C)=\text{ri}\left(\overline{C}\right)$?

What about for general topological vector spaces? Thanks.

**Background:** I've been trying to seriously understand results about convex sets in functional analysis. Previously, I've always just take things like Krein-Milman for granted. So initially I'm trying to see whether we always have $\text{ri}(C)\neq \emptyset$. But there's a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/389454/416552). Then I guessed maybe that's true when $C$ is closed? Then, I can see the same counterexample still stands when taking the closure. Another counterexample for closed convex set is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3574557/416552). These counterexamples make me wonder whether the statement above is true.

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you shouldn't just state a question like this. What are your thoughts?  What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @RobertIsrael What do you mean? I originally tried to prove $ri(C)\neq \emptyset$ for every convex set. Then I realized there are counterexamples. So I tried if it's true for closed convex sets. Then I also found counterexamples on this site. So now I ended up with the stated question. I have no idea how to go tackle it at all.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Btw, I'm self-learning with no source of help other than this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$, you can have a proper subspace $E$ that is dense.  $E$ is convex, and $\text{ri}(E) = E$, but $\text{ri}(\overline{E}) = \overline{E} = X$.